# Java Generic class bound to type extending T<E>

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have a generic test class that is generic over the type of a collection (stack in my case) it tests.

Let the name of the generic type be `S` (for Stack). I have an interface `IStack<E>` and I want to require `S` to implement `IStack<E>`.
When I declare my class as
`class Test<S extends IStack> { ... }`,
I get a warning:

> IStack is a raw type, References ... should be parameterized.

`class Test<S<E> extends IStack<E>>` leads to a syntax error

> Syntax error on token '<', , expected

What's the right way to declare this kind of bound in Java?

Comment: `class Test<S extends IStack<?>>` should work.

Comment: If `E` is already bound, you want `class Test<S extends IStack<E>>`.  If `E` is unbound, then `class Test<S extends IStack<?>>` should be just fine.

Comment: This might sound flippant but the test frameworks I use would declare this as `class Test` with no type parameter.  Java generics don't work the way most people expect and aren't reifiable, hence there's no real value trying to parameterize a class in this manner.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need two generic parameters, one for element, another one for stack type, i.e.

```
class Test<E,S extends IStack<E>>
```

(or `E extends SomeAncestorOfYourElements` if needed)

Comment: This worked, as well as the `S extends IStack<?>` answer below did, but when initializing a stack as `S<Integer> bla = new S<>();` I get the error "The type S is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>". Is there a way to do this "Give me some stack implementation, I'll test it no matter what explicit Stack it is?" thing?

Comment: @Anton Your C# background is evident ;) In Java it works differently, though. You need to either: 1) pass an instance of `Supplier<S>` to the constructor (e.g. `SomeStack::new`) and call `supplier.get()`, or: 2) pass an instance of `Class<S>` (e.g. `SomeStack.class`) and call `stackClass.newInstance()`.

Answer (score 2):

`class Test<S extends IStack>` uses a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) of `IStack`, there is no compile-time information of what is inside `IStack`.

You can do few things, it's entirely up to your design:

- `class Test<S extends IStack<?>>` to allow for any element type in `IStack`
- `class Test<E, S extends IStack<E>>` to bind `IStack` to a specific `E` element type
- `class Test<S extends IStack<S>>` to confuse everyone